# Validate input text rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

How do I make a text field only accept letters in rails, enter a number by keyboard and do not reflect in the input.
I´m using client side validation for sever

Comment: I want that when I press some number I do not appear anything in the input

Answer (score 0):

```
validates_format_of :atr, :table, :with => /^[a-z]+$/i
```

/^[a-z]+$/i 
will only allows letters only. The following is the details of the regex.

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_format_of

```
^     => Start of line
[a-z] => Any single character in the range a-z
+     => One or more characters of the range
$     => End of line
i     => To make case insensitive
```